# Is this weird that : using testng to test in struts2, the request field doesn't exist?

Tags: struts2, testng

I am a newer to struts2.
I am doing testing in struts2 using struts2-testng-plugin, and I am following the struts documentation, it says request of `MockHttpServletRequest` will be available by extending `StrutsTestCase`. Well, I do it, let my test class extends the `StrutsTestCase`. What a surprise I can not get the request field. Then I look at the `StrutsTestCase` in the struts2-testng-plugin-2.3.15.1.jar, again let me surprise, there aren't any field like request, response.So, I just want check are there something like request and response field in struts2-junit-plugin-2.3.15.1.jar.Actually it has all of them.

So, could you tell how can I test the struts using testng-plugin?

Comment: What Struts2 documentation are you referring to?

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/testng-plugin.html, this is the testng-plugin, http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/unit-testing.html,this is using junit-plugin, it works using junit-plugin, but fails with testng-plugin.

Comment: There are different `StrutsTestCase` classes.

Comment: I know they are different, but how can I do the test with the request of MockHttpServletRequest using testng-plugin.Should I add the filed request in my test class? I don't think that works correctly.

Comment: You can examine the source code of struts2-junit-plugin and see how request is initialized in there.

Comment: Yea, I have done that.Now the struts2 supports both test plugins actually, I am confusing with they aren't in the same methodology.May be there are some other special ways. Thanks a lot.